# ffmpeg failed to drop stream with unsupported codec

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, mp4, codec

I've mp4 file what uploaded by user, when play it with some player, where will popup some warn.
I check the video and found something like `Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2`. So I want to drop it.
I use `-map 0:a -map 0:v` to only select the video and audio stream, but it not works(not drop the data stream).

Here is the source mp4 info

```
$ ffprobe.exe 9846ad1fbce094023e5978b090699d46.mp4
ffprobe version git-2019-12-08-9f7b2b3 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191125
...........
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '9846ad1fbce094023e5978b090699d46.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:02:59.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4867 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le, 856x480 [SAR 320:321 DAR 16:9], 4728 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

Here is what I've tried

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=index,codec_type,codec_name -of csv -i 9846ad1fbce094023e5978b090699d46.mp4
stream,0,h264,video
stream,1,aac,audio
stream,2,unknown,data

$ ffmpeg -v error -i 9846ad1fbce094023e5978b090699d46.mp4 -map 0:a -map 0:v -y out.mp4

$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=index,codec_type,codec_name -of csv -i out.mp4
stream,0,aac,audio
stream,1,h264,video
stream,2,unknown,data
```

I've also tried(Neither works)

```
ffmpeg -i 9846ad1fbce094023e5978b090699d46.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -map_chapters -1 out.mp4 
ffmpeg -i 9846ad1fbce094023e5978b090699d46.mp4 -c copy -dn -map_metadata:c -1 out.mp4
```

Comment: you have to reencode video because "yuv422p10le" is not available for all players, include all web browsers, in fact, may be you can listen the audio but no see video.

Comment: Try to encode video and copy the audio: ffmpeg -i  uservideo.mp4 -map 0:v   -c:v libx264 -crf 1  -map 0:a -c copy -strict -2 -movflags -faststart  -preset veryfast -dn -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 new_video.mp4